# array_diff & renumbering numeric keys

Tags: php, arrays, key, numeric

```
(I'm a beginner)
```

My script uses the standard

```
$c = 0;
$t = count($array);

while ($c < $t) {
  $blah = $array[$c];
  ++$c;
}
```

rather extensively. But I just ran into a situation where I also need `array_diff` and it breaks that all to hell because now the numeric keys have gaps. I'm getting `Undefined offset` errors all over the place.

How do I reset the numeric keys of an array? The order of the objects in the array is irrelevant.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To reset the keys, you can use [`array_values()`](http://fi.php.net/array_values):

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to reset the keys of you array : you have to change the way you are going through it.

Instead of using a `while` loop and accessing the array elemnts by index, you should use a foreach loop, which will only get you elements from the array :

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // $key contains the index of the current element
    // $value contains the value of the current element
}
```

Comment: +1 for you because I'll certainly use that knowledge elsewhere. But the check has to go to Tatu for hitting the bullseye. Thank you Pascal.

Comment: @Andrew : you're welcome :-) ;; Yeah, I know I wasn't really answering the question, but I thought this would be useful anyway *(and I always use foreach to loop over arrays elements)* ;; and as I saw another answer already talked about the `array_values`, I didn't put it in mine.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, I really do. I'm still getting my feet wet and am recognizably in the "I've got a really kickass hammer" phase of learning to program. So again, thank you for the expansive and helpful push down the road towards more appropriate code design.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Tatu.

**For the lulz,** I will share with you the following idiot hack I used while waiting for a sensible answer:

```
$badArray = array_diff($allData, $myData);

$string = implode(",",$badArray);

$dump = explode(",",$string);

$goodArray = $dump;
```

worked. Made me feel all dirty, but it worked.